# Chromium showing scroll bars in electron app permanently?

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I have not changed anything from earlier today till now and all of the sudden I see scroll bars in my electron app. I checked in Chromium since that is what electron uses and I have the sam issue. Usually when you scroll the bar shows up but then goes away. It is permanently there in Electron, Chromium, and Chrome. What could have changed from earlier till now?

This makes the styling in the app look ugly with permanent scroll bars if something can scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a setting that got switched somehow. If you are on mac and you you go to System Preferences > General > Show Scroll Bars, you can set it there. It was on show.